# How to open a different modal on each tab?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, tabs, modal-dialog

I'm trying to open a modal on each tab item but the modal only opens on the first tab. If I click on any item other than the first and try to open the modal, it will be open on the first item.

The other problem is that I can't open a modal when I add new items. Starting `tabs = []` does not work. How to solve it?

see an example

https://jsfiddle.net/gerald3ebd/k7abtf35/

Comment: Can you please edit tag and add materialize as your question is specific to materialized problem. And always try to add code as snippet in your question as I did in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three tab's are targeting to same modal, make it separate/different by changing id/href as different.

```js
Vue.use(VueTabs);
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    tabs: ['First tab', 'Second tab', 'Third tab']
  },
  methods: {
    removeTab(index){
      this.tabs.splice(index, 1)
    },
    addTab(){
      this.tabs.push('New Tab');
      var vm = this;
      setTimeout(function(){
          var elems = document.querySelectorAll('#modal'+(vm.tabs.length-1));
          M.Modal.init(elems);
      },100);
       
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        M.AutoInit()
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
        M.Modal.init(elems);
      })
  }
})
```

```css
.tab-close{
  float:right;
}
.tab-close:hover{
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/cristijora/vue-tabs/master/dist/vue-tabs.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/cristijora/vue-tabs/master/themes/material.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/lykmapipo/themify-icons/master/css/themify-icons.css">

<div id="app">
 <button @click="addTab">Add new tab</button>
 <vue-tabs type="pills">
    <v-tab v-for="tab,index in tabs" :key="tab">
       <div slot="title">{{tab}} <span @click.stop="removeTab(index)" class="ti-close tab-close"></span></div>
       {{tab}} 
         <!-- Modal Trigger -->
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" :href="'#modal'+index">Modal_{{index}}</a>

          <!-- Modal Structure -->
          <div :id="'modal'+index" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <h4>Modal Header</h4>
              <p>A bunch of text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
            </div>
          </div>
    </v-tab>
</vue-tabs>

</div>
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much. But the question of not opening the modal in a new item added remains.

Comment: In addition, the modal only opens if the array starts non-empty. Is tabs = [ ] it just doesn't work

Comment: I don't understand, where it is not working ?, can you check here forked from you fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/gnrwpac9/

Comment: Just click in "Add new tab" and try to open a modal by the new tab added

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to do. Have you read the modal page? https://materializecss.com/modals.html Modals are triggered via `.modal-trigger` class, and the target is set by the href, which must be unique (href="#my-target1"). Then, the corresponding modal must have the matching id `<div class="modal" id="my-target1">`

Comment: Yes, I read. Even placing a unique id for each modal you cannot open a modal with # id-1 on the first tab or a modal with # id-5 on the fifth tab. The idea is very simple, but I cannot implement it. I don't know how Vuejs is handling this logic. Just add a fourth tab and you will see that the fourth modal present in this fourth tab does not open.

Comment: @GeraldBern: I have updated my answer to fix to open newly added modal.

Comment: So every time we want to get the reference of an id or a class we need to do it with var vm = this? At first I tried to use a document.querySelector but I was discouraged from doing so by the recommendation of Vuejs himself who asks to use v-if instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help and I'm sorry if I wasn't very clear in my comments. You taught a lot!

Comment: Your question was clear, I read question in hurry. I am happy if you learned something.